# can not reinstall grub after windows install: btrfs subvolumes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, btrfs

(To clarify: this is about fixing grub by using a LiveCD to rebuild grub, a pretty standard operation e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows,
with the difficulty being btrfs in use)

Ubuntu partition is /dev/sda5 and is btrfs, with encrypted home.

When I

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
cd /mnt 
ls
```

I get two directories: @ and @home
and the / file system is under @

```
chroot /mnt
```

fails with 'failed to run command /bin/bash'

```
chroot /mnt/@
```

looks like it works, since it lets me mount the /proc /dev etc via

```
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
```

but 
`update-grub` fails with

```
grub-probe: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
```

fstab looks like this:

```
UUID=<...> / btrfs defaults,subvol=@ 0 1
```

swap and home are encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the trick with the subvolume is to mount the partition like this:

```
sudo mount -t btrfs -o subvol=@ /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

update-grub succeeds.

I needed to do these steps as well (via [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows))

```
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub # In order to find and add windows to grub menu.
```